# Setting up on a Poweredge 2400

Tags: system-installation

I just received an old Dell Poweredge 2400. I have only been able to successfully install Ubuntu Server 8.10 on this system. But as this is no longer supported I was wanting to see if there are any supported versions I can run on this system. I have tried insatlling several other versions but the installs have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to a newer version, type `do-release-upgrade` in a Terminal. This should install the latest version of your operating system. For more detail, follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html).